# Facebook Authentication: To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

Have a Cordova iOS app with Facebook authentication using Facebook Cordova Plugin.https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Was working fine but has suddenly authentication is failing, having not changed anything in the app that I can see. And I get a warning which I can't find on Google:

"To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings."

The only thing I did yesterday really was add the app to iTunes Connect to use in Testflight. I have it registered as a web app still in Facebook. Could it somehow be related to that? That seems bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

Well the answer was in the question. I added a native iOS app in Facebook. And it now works. Not sure why it was working and suddenly stopped, but hey that's Facebook.

I'll leave this answer here as there were zero hits on Google for that FB warning.

Comment: What was the solution for that warning? I am facing the same. I am already logged in with facebook in facebook native app.... Now I am trying to login with facebook using native app but as soon I tap on open dialog, facebook native app opes and shows the warning !! 

So please tell me the solution.